# Create letsencryot ssl for both IPV4 and IPV6 + reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

i have a vps with ipv6 ::ffff:8b3b:e2ee and 139.59.226.237, i plan to add ssl to my ipv6 and using nginx with reverse proxy to other ip https://139.59.226.237.

If i dont include [::]:80 and [::]:443, ipv4 can do reverse proxy without problem, but the ipv6 will got warning for the ssl problem. After i added [::]:80 and [::]:443 to my domain.conf , when open with ipv4 redirected to https://139.59.226.238:9443 and ipv6 redirected to https://[::ffff:8b3b:e2ee]:9443 and both cant be open with error message :
The webpage at https://139.59.226.238:9443/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

is it possible to install ssl letsencrypt for ipv6 address ?
and what is the correct nginx config to use https://[::ffff:8b3b:e2ee] only without port?

what i've try so far :

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen  [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://139.59.226.237;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
    server {
    listen 443;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
    server_name localhost;
# SSL configuration starts
       ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/ssl/ip.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ssl/ip.key;
       ssl_dhparam /home/ssl/dhparam.pem;
       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
# SSL configuration ends
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://139.59.226.237:443;
       proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

thank you before and all help area really appreciate!

Comment: AFAIK LetsEncrypt does not offer Certificates for IP addresses; neither for IPv4 nor IPv6 IP addresses and only on host names or has that been changed ?

Comment: [IPv6 ::ffff:(32bits) is a special way to represent an IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Transition_from_IPv4). Telling an IPv6-aware stack to connect to ::ffff:8b3b:e2ee actually makes an _IPv4_ connection to 139.59.226.238 and if that's your nginx it won't be able to distinguish this from a connection that actually used the IPv4 address.

Comment: Nothing in your config indicates anything should be listening on port `9443`. Hence, it is either expected or out of the scope of this question that the site there is down.